# Using css calc with viewport units

Tags: css, calc, viewport-units

Why does this work:

```
left: calc(50vw - (269 * (100vw  / 1220 ) ) );
```

But this doesn't:

```
left: calc(50vw - (269 * (100vw  / 1220 ) ) + 269 );
```

The only difference being + 269.

FF inspector says 'invalid property value'.

Comment: You can multiply and divide by unitless values, but addition and subtraction requires units.

Comment: Thanks, do you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: Sure, will do—one sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `calc()`, you can multiply and divide by unitless values, but addition or subtraction requires units.

`calc(10vh * 2)` — This is ok, and means "I want twice as many `vh` as I started with".

`calc(10vh + 2)` — This isn't ok. "Plus two what: `vh`? `px`?".

Comment: @oldboy Please ask that as a new question instead of commenting on an unrelated answer.

Comment: unrelated? isnt your answer (and this question) addressing this exact matter?

Comment: @oldboy No. Please ask a separate question.